# Type check an Any variable for Data Class

Tags: kotlin

I have a class that has a constructor of type Any. I'm passing an instance of a Data Class to that constructor. How can I type check the Any variable to make sure it contains a Data Class?

What I tried so far:

```
private var myObject : Any

fun dataClassTypeCheck(): Boolean {
      if (myObject is KClass<*>) {return true}
      return false
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need it need to be a `data class`?

Comment: I'm just playing around with Kotlin to be honest. I'm trying to dependency inject a data object. I couldn't create a data class interface so I've been trying to find a way around it.

Comment: myObject.javaCalass.kotlin.isData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if `myObject` has a type which is a data class then it's:
`myObject::class.isData`.

If you want to know if `myObject` is a KClass object of a data class then it's: `myObject.isData`

Answer (score 0):

if you have Class<?>:

```
MyObjectClass::class.java.kotlin.isData
```

and if you have instance of class:

```
myObject.javaCalass.kotlin.isData
```